# theme_key does not switch theme when URL user/<uid>/edit is called

Tags: theming, users

Hello fellows and Gurus,

I am having a problem with a mobile theme of our standard website (running Drupal 7)

We therefore have two URLs:

- mywebsite.com
- m.mywebsite.com

We use the [ThemeKey](https://drupal.org/project/themekey) module to redirect to the correct theme/templates. We also tried [Mobile Tools](https://drupal.org/project/mobile_tools), but it does not work any better, so it is currently disabled.

For most pages, the url detection works and successfully redirects to the mobile theme when `m.mywebsite.com/<somepage>` is called.

However, when user wants to edit his own profile (`m.mywebsite.com/user/<uid>/edit`), the standard page is shown instead.

Same happens with the "cancel account page" (`m.mywebsite.com/user/<uid>/cancel`).

However the registration page (`m.mywebsite.com/user/register`), and the forgot your password page (`m.mywebsite.com/user/password`) works OK. Even when the user is connected for the latter.

Any ideas of what could be wrong in our configuration/code ?

Comment: What happens when you remove the extra forward slashes from the paths? e.g. `m.mywebsite.com/user/edit`

Comment: Thanks for your quick feedback ! 

Actually I tested this. It returns an "Access denied message". 

Same happens on the standard URL (mywebsite.com/user/edit), by the way.

Actually instead of the double forward slashes, one should read mywebsite.com/user/[uid]/edit. I should have url-encoded my  &lta; and &gta;

Comment: Do you have a specific administration theme set in your Appearance settings? If you disable the admin theme, does it correct the issue?

Comment: It might have something to do with the fact a user edit page is normally handled by the admin theme...can you disable that for the time being to test?

Comment: @sheena_d Great minds eh? ;)

Comment: Hello again, 

I tested as suggested, by disabling the "Admin theme" (seven). Cleared cache, but the behaviour is the same, both on backoffice and frontoffice.

Comment: Actually it works ! 
First, I disabled "seven" but not under the right section (which is administration theme). 

But now all my back-office is so tiny (mobile-size) !! Is there a way to force these two pages to use the mobile theme ONLY with the "m" prefix and keep the back-office as it was ? 
For the time-being, I reverted. 

I used this tutorial [http://www.absolutecross.com/tutorials/drupal/theming-the-user-account-page-in-drupal] as a starter to theme the user account page (and it works OK on the standard site).

Answer (score -1):

Here is the answer : http://drupal.org/node/1130158

To quote:

> `user/%/edit is` an admin path. See [function user_admin_paths](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_admin_paths/7) for details.
>
> So if you enabled an "Administration theme" at "`/admin/appearance`", this theme will be applied instead of any theme configured using ThemeKey.

Also: Don't forget to specify "system" in your settings for theme_key.